# Gnuplot no variable "pause"

Tags: gnuplot

With the following gnuplot script

```
set logscale y
set title "Residuals"
set ylabel 'Residual'
set xlabel 'Iteration'
plot "< cat log | grep 'solving for p' | cut -d ' ' -f9 | tr -d ','" title 'p' with lines,\
pause 1
```

and this version

```
$ gnuplot --version
gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 2
```

I get the following error:

```
"residuals", line 6: undefined variable: pause
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your plot command is incorrect because the line ends with ",\" which means your line is continuing and `pause` is being treated as a variable passed to plot. So pause doesn't exist.

I suggest removing ",\".

Comment: matt's analysis is correct.  It is worth noting, however, that in gnuplot 5 terminating a 'plot' command with a comma produces a warning but the program will continue anyway so that sequence would work.

Comment: @Ethan, ahh, formatting caught me there. I was mainly pointing out the "\" causes it to continue onto the second line.